# Subversion or svn get status in repository

Tags: svn, repository, status

I want to find out if there are any files not checked-in in the svn repository from client.

ie SVN status in repository.

I can run script, command, ...  all I have is repository location and I have to run it from a client machine (not in repository).

User1: CheckedOut File X, FileY

User2: CheckedOut File Z.

Total 3 files are currently checked out.

**Update:**
I guess, I am asking wrong question. Is there a concept of checking out a file before modifying a file like in clearcase tool.

So we can get the status of Locks in repository? eg:

user A locked 1, 2, 3 files
user C locked 5.

Total 4 files are locked.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. You're trying to find out if you have any files in the local repo that aren't in the remote repo?

Answer (score 0):

In Subversion the repository doesn't track individual working copies. The checkout operation is not exclusive, so can even be performed by users that can't modify the repository.

Since Subversion 1.1, Subversion does allow exclusive locks by using `svn lock PATH -m "Why"`. These locks are usually stored in one working copy and on the repository.

In this case you can't commit to a locked location without obtaining this lock first.

See http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.advanced.locking.html for more information about these locks.